# Why does std::array not have an operator T*?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, stdarray

With C arrays, it's been the case that simply naming an array has the same effect as writing `&foo[0]` for something approaching 50 years.

When converting from C style arrays to std::array<> in a project I'm working on, the vast majority of "error"s that appeared were due to the above property of C arrays.

In all cases, the solution was trivial, just append `.data()`.  However it occurred to me that a carefully crafted `operator T*` ought to directly solve this issue.

Is there any technical reason this operator could not be created?

Comment: Personally I think it is safer to have to call `.data()` that what we get with builtin arrays.

Comment: *Is there any good reason this operator doesn't exist?* -- Great -- another operator being called at runtime without the programmer potentially being aware of it.  If you notice, most of the C++ standard library stays away from casting operators (maybe all of the standard library does).  Realize that `std::string` and in general `std::basic_string<>` also does not have a `operator char*()`, and instead, provide a `c_str()` function.  My experience is that a C++ programmer that litters their codebase with casting operators many times do not know themselves what functions are being called.

Comment: @sepp2k Yeah, it's operator T* I'm looking for.  I had a look at some code I have from years ago that did this for something else.  In the intervening time, my memory had faded, we were using `operator T` in that context which allowed direct access. Most of the time at least, it did somewhat rely on the ability of the compiler to infer the target type at runtime.  In 99% of cases it worked right, and for the 1% where it didn't we had a `.get()` method to cover.  I've edited the question appropriately.

Comment: Not implicitly decaying to pointers is one of the most significant advantages of using `std::array` over builtin arrays.

Comment: @L.F. Implicit conversion is not "decay".

Comment: An excellent question! (Implicit conversions aren't evil, and neither are information losing conversions.)

Comment: @curiousguy Builtin arrays decay to pointers. Are you questioning this sentence?

Comment: @L.F. `std::array` is not a builtin array and user defined conversions are nothing like argument decay. Are you questioning this sentence?

Comment: @curiousguy I said "Not implicitly decaying to pointers is one of the most significant advantages of using `std::array` over builtin arrays." Essentially, it means that builtin arrays implicitly decay to pointers (this is true) and that `std::array` does not implicitly decay to pointers (this is also true). Are you questioning this sentence? ;-)

Comment: @L.F. Nope... you are correct. :D

Answer (score 5):

C-style arrays are sized constructs. You can get the compile-time size of an array via various means. However, when the array decays into a pointer, you lose that compile-time sizing information. Even if the parameter is an "array" type, it's really still just a pointer with no size info. You can use template programming to preserve the size if the array is passed as a function parameter (`template<size_t S> void func(T(&param)[S])`), but that's it.

This implicit decaying of an array to a pointer is considered by many C++ programmers to be a *design flaw* in C-style arrays. Indeed, it would hardly be unreasonable to say that lossy conversions are probably not ones which should be implicit. Given that `std::array` is an attempt to fix as many of the flaws of C-style arrays as possible, allowing it to implicitly decay into a pointer would be counter-productive.

By contrast, [C++20's `std::span` type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) provides an implicit conversion from a `std::array` (and C-style arrays, among others). The reason being that such a conversion preserves the information: pointer as well as size. Indeed, the conversion can even preserve the compile-time nature of that size.

---

> Is there any technical reason this operator could not be created?

"**Could** not"? No.

Answer (score 1):

data() is introduced to have similar interface across multiple STL containers. For example, std::string and std::vector also provide data() which gives address of actual data buffer. So std::array interface was designed to match that. Operator() that you suggest is quite different way, and doesn't seem to be absolutely appropriate. As above commenters also mentioned, the more appropriate is operator T*(), but still this is not how STL designers preferred to do - they introduced data(). Why? Maybe because it is just more readable.

Comment: "_Operator()_" Do you mean `operator()()`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any good reason this operator doesn't exist?

If you mean why there is no `operator T*()` to automatically provide the cast, one (of multiple) potential reasons is exactly that -- the idea of *automatic* casting.

Maybe it would be convenient to have the code using `std::array` to just compile correctly by utilizing `operator T*()`, and away you go with a program that has been built with no errors.  However there are some implications to this:

1) The call to `operator T*()` is a potential runtime cost that the programmer may not have desired, but just comes along for the ride.  In C++, the goal is to only pay for what is desired, and having casting operators just impose themselves goes against this idea.

2) `operator T*()` and casting operators in general can potentially hide bugs or
    bottlenecks in running code, due to usage that the programmer is not aware of.

In my experience, ask a programmer that has a code base littered with casting operators what functions are actually being called, and more times than not, they are not sure what path their code is taking, or they are just plain wrong (and don't realize it until they partake in a debugging session and see all the twists and turns being done by the seemingly innocent casting operators being invoked).

Thus it is deemed far safer for the programmer to explicitly want to "convert" the data by calling a function such as `data()`, and not by utilizing a `operator T*()` they may not have been aware of.

Comment: **Casting** is never automatic: it requires writing a cast. The problem here is automatic **conversions**. +1.

Comment: As for performance, with the way modern optimizers behave, that's largely a non-issue.  https://godbolt.org/z/gbRHuL shows this very nicely, for both GCC and MSVC at maximum optimizations, the conversion is free.

Comment: @dgnuff -- Unless you can absolutely guarantee that using such an operator will not incur any runtime cost in any scenario, then it's a non-starter.  That's why I said a *potential* bottleneck.  It practically has to be `constexpr` in all situations, and that can't be guaranteed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Which C++ construct (which isn't 100% compile time) has such no runtime cost guarantee?

Answer (score -2):

Calling `data()` is a thing you should avoid. It can be useful to have this power for (as in our case migrating code or optimized code processing the guts) however it goes against the safety net `std::array` provides.

```
 std::array<int, 2> a{1,2};
 auto* ptr = a.data();
 std::cout << ptr[2]; // boom
```

Things taking away a safety net should be explicit.

Comment: std::array's `operator[]` does not have any bounds checking. Ergo `a.data()[2]` is as unsafe as `a[2]`. (**Though any decent compiler will most likely catch this)

Comment: Which I more attribute to design with compatibility than good. For performance critical code I'd prefer if `operator[]` were changed and `at_unsafe()` were added. 
That aside: There is a second aspect: `std::array` carries the type around in its declaration making it readily available (both  in code review and for lookup), the pointer returned by `data()` loses that.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is implemented in `std::array::at`. If you want bounds checking, prefer `at` over `operator[]`.